# Do and Undo action in the same / different page - Is there a difference?

Tags: web-development, web, ajax

If I'm bulding an application like a social network and I implement a like / favorite button with AJAX, is it preferable to use one URL to like / dislike or 2 differents URL?

If I use one, for example `like.php`, in that url I'd check if the post ID was already liked or not, and then do the opposite action.

If I use two, for example `like.php` and `dislike.php`, in those urls I'd check if the post ID was already liked or not liked, and then return an error if the action was already done.

I'd say the first option is easier, because it requires less backend/frontend code, but many big websites use the second method. Is there a reason behind that?

Comment: Repeat like/dislike should probably just be idempotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first scheme, your endpoint is not idempotent (i.e. if you execute it twice it doesn't do the same thing as executing it once).  With the latter scheme, you can easily implement it to be idempotent (and potentially use a PUT method).  In this case, if the "user" likes something they've liked before, it should just succeed and do nothing.  This allows requests to be replayed in the face of intermittent network connections.

There's also a mild maintenance benefit by splitting them up, arguably.  Each endpoint does one thing and one thing only with no conditional logic.  (The fault-tolerance and benefits with respect to concurrency are far more significant though.)

Comment: You could use a single URI but make it idempotent through the use of HTTP request verbs (i.e. PUT to like something and DELETE to remove a like). This seems syntactically preferable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically it is a create or update scenario, which is what PUT (which is also idempotent) means.

so make a HTTP PUT request to a single endpoint with the value for like.

```
{like: true}
```

for liking and

```
{like: false}
```

for disliking.

Answer (score 0):

With the second approach there is potentially a performance benefit, because you can update directly the DB without checking if the post is already liked / disliked. 
(Only an update, versus a SELECT and then an UPDATE)

Probably you already know if the post is to be liked or to be disliked, because this action come from a GUI which show only the relevant button (if the post is liked show the "dislike" or the opposite).

There isn't even the need to show an error if the post is already liked and you want to like it, because that means there is not a change of state for the post.

Note that you may also use a single endpoint but with differents verbs, like PUT and DELETE so you can achieve the same performance benefit as i stated, but using a single endpoint instead of 2.

> I'd say the first option is easier, because it requires less backend/frontend code, but many big websites use the second method. Is there a reason behind that?

In the end, the real answer to your question is , **it depends on other factors , potentially is only a preference**